# How do I paginate Parse.com pointers? A list of message senders and receivers, for example

Tags: database, parse-platform, pagination

I'm trying to set up a **scalable** messaging system following [the example offered by Parse.com](http://blog.parse.com/learn/secure-your-app-from-the-data-browser-with-pointer-permissions/). I want to paginate the users that the user has interacted with, that is, the list of `senders` and `receivers`.

I can query for all messages:

```
var senderQuery = new Parse.Query("Messages");
var receiverQuery = new Parse.Query("Messages");

senderQuery.equalTo("sender", request.user);
receiverQuery.equalTo("receiver", request.user);

var query = Parse.Query.or(senderQuery, receiverQuery);
```

But if I paginate this query and have many messages with one user, **I might not see any other users until a few paginations later.**

I'd like to query for just a list of distinct users, but [there's no built-in query constraint that would return distinct values based on a column](https://parse.com/questions/retrieving-unique-values). Parse.com instead recommends that I:

> query for all the rows, then iterate through them and track the distinct values for the desired column

But [Parse won't let me query for more than 1000 objects at a time](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries-query-constraints)), and even if I could, this isn't a scalable approach.

How can I make messaging scalable?

Answer (score 0):

Well for the start, you do not want to query a message table that grows vertically very quickly as it is certainly a bad idea in any scalable database. I suggest you create three `Relation` fields for every user,

1. `Sent` messages by that user,
2. `Received` messages for that user
3. `UserInteractions` to keep a list of all users you interacted with so far.

Now what you want to achieve is easy as you can simply exploit a neat feature of Parse `Relation`. When you add an object (which has already been added before) to a `Relation` field, you will never ever end up with a duplicate record ! This means you can get the list of the distinct users you've interacted with from your third `Relation` even if all the last 100s of messages you sent/received are from only a single user.

Comment: To make sure I understand you correctly, when a message is sent, I create a `messages` object, add 3 relations to the sender `user`, and then 3 relations to the receiver `user`?

Comment: Yes, for every message object created, all three Relations in your sender and Receiver user data needs to be updated with the data. You can automate most of this on Parse cloud easily

Comment: Relations don't preserve order, so the users returned from a paginated `UserInteractions` query aren't guaranteed to be the most recent users interacted with. Any ideas?

Comment: When it comes to order, noSQL database will not be that much of a help as they sacrifice data consistency for speed. As you can see parse has very limited atomic operations and almost no data synchronisation tools. A naive solution is that you can go through each of your users you've interacted with and fetch the latest time you received a message from them, then order your users accordingly.